# Future Builder not running when returning to widget

Tags: android, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

I am running a FutureBuilder with Firebase authentication. i am expecting flutter to check inside a FutureBuilder on the status of the users login. if the user is logged in the widget to display should be a `logout` icon. if the user is logged out then the widget to display should be `login`

My function for the Future is as follows:

```
Future<String> setUserStatus()

async {

userStatus = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();


uid = userStatus.uid;

print('after the query - The user is $uid after');

if(uid == null){

  return uid = null;

} else if( uid != null){

  return uid = userStatus.uid;
}

}
```

My Future Builder is as follows:

```
FutureBuilder<String>(

future: future_user, 
builder: (BuildContext context,  snapshot) {

  String update_status = snapshot.data;

if(update_status == null){
return //Widget for login
}

else if(update_status != null){
return //widget for logout
}
```

This works fine if I click the logout button. The widget updates correctly and gives the user the option to now login. The function for logout is:

```
Future<String> logout() async {
await FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
setState(() {
  future_user = setUserStatus();
});

}
```

The issue is that when I login, the user is taken to a separate Login page. After logging in, when I navigate back to the main page, where the FutureBuider is running, it is not picking up the uid of the User (returns null) and still shows the `login` icon. i am calling the Future Builder inside an initState so should it not be running this when i navigate back?

```
Future<String> future_user;

@override
void initState() {
super.initState();
setState(() {
  future_user = setUserStatus();

});

}
```

when i Re-run the app from Android Studio, it updates the widget correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

initstate will be not called when you navigate back from any other screen bacause of that you are facing that issue.

You can call SetState when you came back from Login screen in following way.

```
 Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => 
    Demo2())).then((value) => {
      setState(() {
           future_user = setUserStatus();
        });
    });
```

I don't know how your user status is changing, so i just demonstrated how you can call some method or whatever you want to do when you came back from login screen so that you can get new data.

Comment: putting my `setState` into the `Navigator` for the login page won't make sense since it is in a separate dart file and `future user` is not a global variable.

Comment: if your data is not in same file then may be you are using and state management system and using that you can call setUserStatus function if that function is responsible for changing state and then you can do setstate.

Comment: Also, I am not navigating to the Main page using Navigator. i am only using the back button on the phone

Comment: it doesn’t matter how you are navigating back then method aways call if you come back from any other screen.

Comment: Thanks! I tried this out now and it works perfectly! Still trying to wrap my head around the state management on Flutter and it seems so strange to input the setState inside the `Navigator.push` function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use call below method at click of login button like below..

```
_navigateAndDisplaySelection(BuildContext context) async {
  final result = await Navigator.push(
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => LoginScreen()),
  );

  // After the Selection Screen returns a result, hide any previous snackbars
  // and show the new result.
     setState(() {
  future_user = result;

});
}
```

And please use `WillPopScope` Widget on Login Page and so when you are clicking on Login Page then after successfully login its directly redirected to main page.

Use `Navigator.pop(context,_loggedInStatus);` in Login Button OnPressed event

Answer (score 0):

Future Builder not running when back to the screen
my solution is to sample

Comment: class A extends to stateful{
    fun(){
        setState(){
           }
    }

    onpressed:Get.to(()=>B(callBack:fun));

}
class B extends to stateful{
    B({this.callBack})
    final callBack;


//somewhere else you want to go

    onpressed:(){Get.to(()=>C(callBack2:callBack));
}

class C extends to stateful{
    C({this.callBack2});
    final callBack2;

    

    function(){
        ----------------
        -------------
        ------------
        Get.back();
        callBack2();

 `enter code here`}